# Change colour of list element when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Right so I have a form, this form has various input boxes and also a checkbox which the user can decide to check.  The user can then click submit on the form and it is stored in the database and produces a list element with its information on a different page.

Is there anyway to change the colour of that list element produced depending on whether the checkbox is checked?

I know there is code such as:

```
$(":checkbox").on('click', function(){
 $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");
});
```

but I don't want the list element of the checkbox to change colour, I want the list element of the form to change colour if the checkbox has been checked inside of that form.  Hope that makes sense.  Is it possible to do this?

HTML for the checbox:

```
<li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkyes" id="checkyes" data-iconpos = "right">
      <label for="checkyes">Unpaid?</label>
</li>
```

Producing the list element from the information given in the form:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM table1', [],
        function(transaction, result) {
            if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                    $('#mylist').append('<li class = "inclist">'+'test'+'</li>');
                }
                $('#mylist').listview().listview('refresh');
            }
        }, 
        errorHandler
    );
}, errorHandler, nullHandler);
```

In relation to the form, the checkbox is inside the form.  So I'm thinking when I click submit, I should somehow store the value of the checkbox inside the db and then use a select statement with a condition?

The HTML for the form itself is just a series of list elements with input boxes.

Comment: Add some relevant HTML

Comment: Alright, let me show my code for the checkbox and generating the list element hang on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use change not click

```
$(":checkbox").on('change', function(){
 $(this).closest("desired element").toggleClass("checked");
});
```